# Flutter how to cancel all FirebaseAuth authStateChanges Subscriptions after hot restart?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

whenever i hot restart the app in debug in Flutter, new Subscriptions keep getting added to `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`.

What I need to know:

- How many subscriptions does `authStateChanges()` already have?
- How can i cancel a subscription on that stream (`authStateChanges()`) if the reference to the subscription is lost due to hot restart?
- How can i guarantee, that my subscription is only fired once?

The problem:
Whenever i hot restart the app multiple (n) times, it fires n times. This is undesired. I want to make sure it only gets subscribed once and i want to make sure to cancel any subscription beforehand.

Here's the code i use:

```dart
  
  StreamSubscription<User?>? subscription;

  void onAuthStateChanged(Function(User?) onAuthStateChanges) async {
    if (subscription == null) {
      subscription =
          FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen(onAuthStateChanges);
    } else {
      // Please do not subscribe
    }
  }
```

I use the following versions:

yaml:
firebase_core: ^1.10.6
firebase_auth: "^3.3.4"

flutter doctor:

- Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1801], locale de-DE)
- Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
- Chrome - develop for the web
- Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.2)
- Android Studio (version 3.2)
- Android Studio (version 2020.3)
- VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.62.2)
- Connected device (4 available)

Comment: You could use a singleton class and manage your subscriptions there